# xcode completion like intellisense

Tags: xcode, sense

I have a question about the xcode. When I write code with XCode  the system requires autocompletions. For example when I Write: `[NSBundle main ]` it shows me `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. That is OK but when I write **`[NSBundle bundle]`** it doesn't show me a mainBundle message option. It only considers the beginning of the function. I want to see mainBundle in recommendations like Visual Studio. Is it possible?

Comment: for few things you can use code-snippets

Answer (score 0):

No. Xcode doesn't use fuzzy autocompletion. There is though [one commercial IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/index.html) that does that (among several other nice things) but of course is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Try AppCode. This IDE supports such autocompletion.

Comment: Thanks for all replies I tried AppCode but is there any possibility to add this property to Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Xcode plugin that adds fuzzy matching to the built-in autocomplete. It even uses Xcode's own fuzzy matcher used in Open Quickly.

https://github.com/chendo/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin